# Angular - employees does no appear in component

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to show register employees in my angular app, but it doesn't appear the values, only creates their items of the array, i make a console.log to see what's wrong and it looks like to be the variables are undefined. Help please

empleado.component.html

```
<div class="row animated fadeIn">
  <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="card-title"> Empleados registrados  </h3>

              <table class="table table-hover" >
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Codigo</th>
                    <th>Posicion</th>
                    <th>Oficina</th>
                    <th></th>  
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr *ngFor="let empleado of empleados">
                    <td>{{empleado.nombre}}</td>
                    <td>{{empleado.codigo}}</td>
                    <td>{{empleado.posicion}}</td>
                    <td>{{empleado.oficina}}</td>
                    <td>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
                      <button class="btn btn-danger"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>

          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

empleado.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Empleado } from '../models/empleado.model';
import { EmpleadoService } from '../services/empleado.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-empleado',
  templateUrl: './empleado.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./empleado.component.css']
})
export class EmpleadoComponent implements OnInit {

  empleados: any[] = [];

  constructor(public empleadoServ: EmpleadoService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.traerEmpleados();
    console.log(this.empleados.length);
  }

  traerEmpleados() {
    this.empleadoServ.getEmpleados()
        .subscribe( (resp: any) => {
          console.log(resp[0].nombre);

            for (let index = 0; index < resp.length; index++) {
              this.empleados[index] = resp[index];
              console.log(this.empleados[index]);
            }
            // JSON.stringify(this.empleados);
            console.log(this.empleados[0].nombre);
        });

  }

}
```

empleado.service.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Empleado } from '../models/empleado.model';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError  } from 'rxjs/operators';


import swal from 'sweetalert';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmpleadoService {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  guardarEmpleado(empleado: Empleado): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.post('http://localhost:62200/api/Empleado', empleado)
                 .pipe(
                   map( (resp: any) => {
                    swal('Empleado creado', empleado.nombre, 'success');
                    return empleado;
                   }),
                   catchError((e: any) => throwError(e))
                 );
  }


  getEmpleados()  {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:62200/api/Empleado');
  }

  borrarEmpleado(id: number): Observable <any> {
    return this.http.delete('http://localhost:62200/api/Empleado/' + id)
                 .pipe(
                   map( (resp: any) => {
                    swal('Empleado eliminado', 'Borrado', 'warning');
                    return resp;
                   }),
                   catchError((e: any) => throwError(e))
                 );
  }

}
```

And when i try to show employees, it creates the items but it doesn't show the name, code, position, office.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your markup, you are using lowercase property names:

```
                <td>{{empleado.nombre}}</td>
                <td>{{empleado.codigo}}</td>
                <td>{{empleado.posicion}}</td>
                <td>{{empleado.oficina}}</td>
```

Yet in the screenshot, it seems the data objects returned from the server are in uppercase.

If you change your markup to use the uppercase property names (`empleado.Nombre`, etc.) I suspect that will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I cannot believe that was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Properties are case sensitive

For example change **empleado.nombre** to **empleado.Nombre**

```
 <tr *ngFor="let empleado of empleados">
                    <td>{{empleado.Nombre}}</td>
                    <td>{{empleado.Codigo}}</td>
                    <td>{{empleado.Posicion}}</td>
                    <td>{{empleado.Oficina}}</td>
                    <td>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
                      <button class="btn btn-danger"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you displaying alert msg in Service. It should be added in Component.

did console.log in service returns result? If yes, try with below code.

**Component:**

```
traerEmpleados() {
    this.empleadoServ.getEmpleados()
        .subscribe( (resp: any) => {
          this.empleados = resp;
        });
  }
```

Comment: It always get error, the problem that i see, it's maybe in the types, when I write console.log(this.empleados[0].nombre); it appears in the console "undefined"